# Joint entropy in python

Tags: python, math, numpy, entropy

I have two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['1','2','3'])
b = np.array(['3','4','1','5'])
```

I want to calculate joint entropy. I've found some materials to make it like:

```
import numpy as np
def entropy(*X):
    return = np.sum(-p * np.log2(p) if p > 0 else 0 
        for p in (np.mean(reduce(np.logical_and, (predictions == c for predictions, c in zip(X, classes))))
        for classes in itertools.product(*[set(x) for x in X])))
```

Seems to work fine with `len(a) = len(b)` but it ends with error if `len(a) != len(b)`

UPD: Arrays `a` and `b` were created from exampled main input:

```
b:3 p1:1 p2:6 p5:7
b:4 p1:2 p7:2
b:1 p3:4 p5:8
b:5 p1:3 p4:4
```

Where array `a` was created from p1 values. So not every line consists of every `pK` but every has `b` property. I need to calculate mutual information `I(b,pK)` for each `pK`.

Comment: This is just a guess, but make sure zip is what you want and not something like [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Comment: You can not build a numpy array this way. Perhaps a pair of parens is missing? Also: What type your data is (strings or integers?).

Comment: @ColonelPanic yes, now I understand zip() isn't the right thing

Comment: @btel I just didn't mention `import numpy as np` and `np.array([..])` just wanted to show you what kind of data I'm using. Data is int chars (so it doesnt matter what to use I think).

Comment: Ok, but still the parentheses "(..)" are missing - so your syntax is wrong.

Comment: @btel good thing you know syntax. The problem is in calculating joint entropy.

Comment: @ColonelPanic tried my code with zip_longest - it's making more pairs if lengths aren't the same but I still get an error of using shapes (3) (4). This def of joint entropy is pretty clean and fast but it doesnt fit with different length arrays :(

Comment: @aromatvanili I really didn't look too hard, I just saw you had issues when lengths were different and thought izip could have been the cause.

Comment: I recommend reading on joint entropy. The idea is that you evaluate joint probability distribution. How are you going to estmate this distribution if you arrays are of unequal lengths?

Comment: @btel yeah Im a bit messy with all that entropies. I found that I need conditional entropy H(X|Y) not joint H(XY).. Would love someone to help me code that part

Comment: The conditional entropy also needs the two arrays to be of equal lenght. In fact you can calculate it from joint entropy and individual entropies -> H(X|Y) = H(X,Y) - H(Y). Perhaps if you give more details, it will be easier to help.

Comment: @btel I must be looking very stupid. Im just tired to much on this point of my global task. Did some update to main topic. Thanks for being active!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have one independent variable (b) and some dependents (pKs), but you do not have all pKs for each b. If this is right, you need to extract only values for b for which you have given pK. For example, for p1, you would have: b = [3, 4, 5] and p1 = [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about the [Joint Shannon Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy), the formula straightforward:

[image]

The problem with this, when I look at what you've done so far, is that you lack `P(x,y)`, i.e. the joint probability of the two variables occurring together. It looks like `a,b` are the individual probabilities for events a and b respectively.

You have other problems with your posted code (mentioned in the comments):

1. Your variables are not a numeric data type `a=["1","2"]` is **not** the same as `a=[1,2]`. One is a string, the other is a number.
2. The length of your input data must be the same, i.e. for every x in A, there must be a y in B *AND* you need to you know the *joint* probability `P(x,y)`.

Comment: Yes. 1. It doesn't matter. 2. That's the point. Main problem of calculating joint entropy is to make `a` and `b` to be the same length without getting incorrect results. I guess it could be done via transfering data from arrays to matrixes.

Comment: @aromatvanili My point is that the joint probability is a _new piece of information_, one that did not look like it was present in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an idea:

- convert data to numbers
- add padding example zeros

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

a = np.array(['1','2','3','0'])
b = np.array(['3','4','1','5'])
aa = [int(x) for x in a]
bb = [int(x) for x in b]
je =  stats.entropy(aa,bb)
print("joint entropy : ",je)
```

> output: 0.9083449242695364